# Google Analytics in a C++ desktop application

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to add Google Analytics tracking to my C++/Qt desktop application. To do that, I'm making a http GET to `http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif` as specified here:
http://automateeverything.tumblr.com/post/20500736298/google-analytics-without-javascript-or-cookies

My URL looks like:

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=5.2.5&utmac=UA-XXXXXXXX-1&utmhn=prot-on.com&utms=1&utmn=1763710005&utmcc=__utma%3D265465294.163654595.1362420921.1362420921.1362420921.1%3B&utmp=%2Freallyallheaders.html&utmcs=-&utmr=-&utmip=127.0.0.1&utmul=es-es&utmfl=-&utmje=-&utmsr=1920x1080&utmhid=957274494
```

And this is my source code:

```
qint64 currentTimestamp = QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch()/1000;
if (this->timeOfFirstVisit == 0)
    this->timeOfFirstVisit = currentTimestamp;
if (this->timeOfPreviousVisit == 0)
    this->timeOfPreviousVisit = currentTimestamp;

QString googleAnalyticsRequestUrl;
QTextStream(&googleAnalyticsRequestUrl) << "http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif"
<< "?utmwv=5.2.5"
<< "&utmac=" << TRACKING_ID
<< "&utmhn=" << HOST_NAME
<< "&utms=" << this->sessionNumberOfQueries
<< "&utmn=" << QString::number(qrand()) //this->generateRandomUTMN()
<< "&utmcc=__utma%3D" << this->domainHash
    << "." << this->sessionId
    << "." << this->timeOfFirstVisit
    << "." << this->timeOfPreviousVisit
    << "." << currentTimestamp
    << ".1%3B"
<< "&utmp=" << QString(QUrl::toPercentEncoding(pageUrl))
<< "&utmcs=-"
<< "&utmr=-"
<< "&utmip=127.0.0.1"
<< "&utmul=" + QLocale::system().name().toLower().replace("_", "-")
<< "&utmfl=-"
<< "&utmje=-"
<< "&utmsr=" + QString::number(QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry().width()) + "x" + QString::number(QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry().height())
<< "&utmhid=" + QString::number(qrand());

this->timeOfPreviousVisit = currentTimestamp;
this->updateSessionNumberOfQueries();

qDebug() << "Sending Google Analytics request: " << googleAnalyticsRequestUrl;

// Send a http GET request to the created URL
QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)),this, SLOT(googleAnalyticsRequestReceived(QNetworkReply *)));
connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)),manager, SLOT(deleteLater()));

QUrl requestUrl(googleAnalyticsRequestUrl);
QNetworkRequest request(requestUrl);

// I see this headers with Firebug, but I think that they are not necessary
request.setRawHeader("Host", "www.google-analytics.com");
request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0");
request.setRawHeader("X-Forwarded-For", "127.0.0.1");
request.setRawHeader("Connection", "close");

manager->get(request);
```

But my page visits never appears in my Google Analytics page... Can you say me if I'm making something bad please?

Comment: Can you invoke your URL directly from a browser? Does it work if invoked that way, and only fails when invoked from the C++ code?

Comment: The same problem from the browser

Comment: That is the response from the server, is it 200 OK for this GET request that you make ?

Comment: @user1204395, in that case, I'd say you problem is not in the C++/Qt code. I'd focus on getting a successful GET via browser before doing any more work on the code.

Comment: The response is always a 200 (anyway returns a 200 although the parameters are invented). I have edited my post to add more information. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Easier workaround to track desktop apps would be to use a specific C++ SDK such as http://www.trackerbird.com. Using Google Analytics for desktop apps can have many perks - see this blog post: http://blog.trackerbird.com/content/tracking-desktop-applications-with-google-analytics-what-you-should-know/  Disclaimer: I am affiliated with company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is open a socket as I this PHP library makes:
http://code.google.com/p/php-ga/source/browse/trunk/src/GoogleAnalytics/Internals/Request/HttpRequest.php#175

I paste my source code:

```
GoogleAnalyticsManager::GoogleAnalyticsManager()
    : domainHash(this->generateDomainHash(HOST_NAME)),
      sessionId(qrand()),
      sessionNumberOfQueries(1),
      timeOfFirstVisit(0),
      timeOfPreviousVisit(0)
{

}

void GoogleAnalyticsManager::sendPageVisit(const char *pageUrl)
{
    QTcpSocket socket;
    socket.connectToHost("www.google-analytics.com", 80);
    socket.waitForConnected();
    if (socket.state() != QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState) {
        qDebug() << "Impossible to connect to www.google-analytics.com";
        return;
    }

    qint64 currentTimestamp = QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch()/1000;
    if (this->timeOfFirstVisit == 0)
        this->timeOfFirstVisit = currentTimestamp;
    if (this->timeOfPreviousVisit == 0)
        this->timeOfPreviousVisit = currentTimestamp;

    QString googleAnalyticsRequest;
    QTextStream(&googleAnalyticsRequest) << "GET /__utm.gif"
    << "?utmwv=5.2.5"
    << "&utmac=" << TRACKING_ID
    << "&utmhn=" << HOST_NAME
    << "&utms=" << this->sessionNumberOfQueries
    << "&utmn=" << QString::number(qrand())
    << "&utmcc=__utma%3D" << this->domainHash
        << "." << this->sessionId
        << "." << this->timeOfFirstVisit
        << "." << this->timeOfPreviousVisit
        << "." << currentTimestamp
        << ".1%3B"
    << "&utmp=" << QString(QUrl::toPercentEncoding(pageUrl))
    << "&utmcs=-"
    << "&utmr=-"
    << "&utmip=127.0.0.1"
    << "&utmul=" + QLocale::system().name().toLower().replace("_", "-")
    << "&utmfl=-"
    << "&utmje=-"
    << "&utmsr=" + QString::number(QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry().width()) + "x" + QString::number(QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry().height())
    << "&utmhid=" + QString::number(qrand())
    << " HTTP/1.0\r\n"
    << "Host: www.google-analytics.com\r\n"
    << "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0\r\n"
    << "X-Forwarded-For: 127.0.0.1\r\n"
    << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n\r\n";

    this->timeOfPreviousVisit = currentTimestamp;
    this->updateSessionNumberOfQueries();

    qDebug() << "Sending Google Analytics request: " << googleAnalyticsRequest;

    socket.write(googleAnalyticsRequest.toStdString().c_str());
    socket.waitForBytesWritten();
    socket.close();
}

int GoogleAnalyticsManager::generateDomainHash(const QString &domain)
{
    int hash = 1;

    if (domain != NULL && !domain.isEmpty()) {
        hash = 0;

        for (int pos = domain.length()-1; pos >= 0; pos--) {
            int current = domain.at(pos).toAscii();
            hash = ((hash << 6) & 0xfffffff) + current + (current << 14);
            int leftMost7 = hash & 0xfe00000;

            if(leftMost7 != 0) {
                hash ^= leftMost7 >> 21;
            }
        }
    }

    return hash;
}

void GoogleAnalyticsManager::updateSessionNumberOfQueries()
{
    this->sessionNumberOfQueries++;

    if (this->sessionNumberOfQueries > 500) {
        this->sessionId = qrand();
        this->sessionNumberOfQueries = 1;
        this->timeOfFirstVisit = 0;
        this->timeOfPreviousVisit = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Sadly Google does not have an official Qt library available. I however recommend you to look into their Google Analytics API (currently in beta) https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/
This also says that it'll always return a 200 even if your request was invalid and wasn't processed correctly. They're more likely to support you using this beta API then reverse engineering their javascript to use that directly.

Edit: Also looking at your code, it is probably wiser to start with a QUrl right away and add query items using http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qurl.html#addQueryItem so Qt will take care about the correct encoding and all that.

Comment: Checking http://code.google.com/p/php-ga/source/browse/trunk/src/GoogleAnalytics/Internals/Request/HttpRequest.php#175 I see htat this library opens a socket and send the requests (with the same format of my question). It works! :)

Comment: Could you show me your working code? I was looking into integrating analytics into my Qt app just last week and I kinda stop looking after I found out about the beta api.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little class (contained in a single file header) for sending measurement events to Google Analytics from a Qt app:

https://github.com/tesch1/qt-google-analytics-collector

of course, remember to follow Google's privacy policy about not sending personally identifying info, informed consent, and offering your users opt-out...

Answer (score 1):

The API has changed to a new [GA4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/verify-implementation?client_type=gtag) version and the old one might get deprecated. I've made a [simple library](https://github.com/ichlubna/SimpleQtGA4) that supports sending events in a similar way as the OP, creating the request based on the new API docs.

There are also other and more complex older solutions as [this](https://github.com/Larpon/QtFirebase) or [this](https://github.com/HSAnet/qt-google-analytics). Or a new [one](https://github.com/564398053/Qt-GoogleAnalytics4).